# DataTables Bootstrap4 IE11 multiple row thead rowspan

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-4, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I am trying to fix the :before :after pseudo styles in IE11. The headings look okay in other standard  browsers but not in IE11 or Edge. 
Bootstrap4 has a default vertical-align:bottom which I'm trying to apply to the datatable icon images, but that doesn't work either. Interesting side note is that fixedHeader is true, and when I scroll down the headings look okay.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(() =>{

    $('#results-table').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            {
                orderable: false, targets: [0, 1]
            }],
        fixedHeader: true,
        order: [[2, 'asc']],
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        scrollCollapse: false,
        // autoWidth: true,
        // heightMatch: 'auto',
        info: false
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
  <table class="table" id="results-table" >
        <thead class="thead-light text-center">            
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">One</th>
                <th rowspan="2" class="">Two</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Three</th>                 
                <th rowspan="2">Four</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Five</th>
                <th colspan="3"> Columns under</th>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">1</th>
                <th scope="col">2</th>
                <th scope="col">3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td>Data4</td>
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td>Data7</td>
            <td>Data8</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: IE Edge]

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test using code below which gave me similar result in IE 11, MS Edge and Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(() =>{

    $('#results-table').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            {
                orderable: false, targets: [0, 1]
            }],
        fixedHeader: true,
        order: [[2, 'asc']],
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        scrollCollapse: false,
        // autoWidth: true,
        // heightMatch: 'auto',
        info: false
    });
});
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <table class="table" id="results-table" >
        <thead class="thead-light text-center">            
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">One</th>
                <th rowspan="2" class="">Two</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Three</th>                 
                <th rowspan="2">Four</th>
                <th rowspan="2">Five</th>
                <th colspan="3"> Columns under</th>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">1</th>
                <th scope="col">2</th>
                <th scope="col">3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td>Data4</td>
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td>Data7</td>
            <td>Data8</td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you for the details. I should've mentioned that I use Bootstrap4 and get the downloaded version of the file. Thus, the styles include the arrow keys and that's where the issue lies.

Comment: I try to make a test with downloaded version of Bootstrap4 in IE 11 which also gave me similar output. https://i.postimg.cc/fb6fyKMh/30.png So it can be possible that something else caused this issue. You can let me know from where you had download the files for Bootstrap. If there is any difference than I will also try to download and try to produce the issue.